# create Method in DAL which returns multiple outputs

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a method in DAL which return DataSet, but now I want multiple outputs from method because my Stored Procedure has Output Parameters.

Please suggest a way to return DataSet and Output Parameter's value from method.

Comment: Please add a code snippet to see what's happening. People would be able to answer your question better by looking at scenario.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just return a class holding your values/objects

```
MyResult result = new MyResult();
result.DataSet = myDataset;
result.OtherValue = someOtherValue;

return result;
```

Comment: My Output parameters are dynamically passed to DAL Method, e.g. sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", objInfo.UserID).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;  hear my out put is UserID, but when I do search for records at that time adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters["@TotalAffectedRows"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output; , so I want to pass output parameters and  I should get outpts, Is this work with this code?

Answer (score 0):

Best practical advice would be to use `out` parameters.

For example:

```
public DataSet GetEmployees(string lastName, out int status)
{
    DataSet ds = ...;
    status = ...;

    return ds;
}
```

Comment: My Output parameters are dynamically passed to DAL Method, e.g. sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", objInfo.UserID).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;  hear my out put is UserID, but when I do search for records at that time adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters["@TotalAffectedRows"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output; , so I want to pass output parameters and  I should get outputs

Comment: so use `ref` instead of `out`. That way you can pass variables to the method and also get variables back.

Answer (score 0):

Either use parameters as out or pass variables by ref and assign them values

```
public String YourMethod(Int64 input, ref string output1, ref string output2)
```